# Out-File output is missing line feeds between lines of data

Tags: arrays, powershell, newline

I am passing in an array of `$users`.

```
PS C:\> $users | ft

ID     DisplayName           AdminID   first  last   Password
----   -----------           -------   -----  ----   --------
Axyz   Axyz, Bill            NBX_Admin Bill   Axyz   Secret
```

The code:

```
$y = @()
$y = "Create Users process.  Run started at $('[{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]' -f (Get-Date))"
foreach ($x in $users) {
    $y += "User $($x.DisplayName) with NNN of $($x.ID)"
}
$y += "Completed at $('[{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]' -f (Get-Date))"
$y | Out-File "Log.txt"
```

`$y` is now an unformatted string array.  When I type `$y` to the screen, it looks great.

If I direct it to `Format-Table`, it looks great (no headings).

When I output it to a file, and type that file at a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), it looks great.

However, when I pull it up in Notepad, all the output appears on a single line.  To be precise, all the data is there, there are no lines of data missing, but there are no CR/LF so all of the data appears on a single line within the file when viewed with Notepad.exe.

Comment: Use `Add-Content`, `Set-Content` instead. Likely this is just an encoding issue. `out-file -Encoding ascii` should get you the results you seek as well.

Comment: The thing that is messing up what you are trying to do here is the second line `$y = ....`. When you set `$y = @()`, you are creating an empty array. When you set `$y = "something"`, you are changing the type from an array to a string. Every `+=` operation you are doing later is still creating a new **string** instead of a new **array**. If you want to use this method, you will need to either cast `$y` as an array (`[array]$y += "something"`) or never change the type by using `+=` in every assignment after the first declaration.

Comment: "out-file -encoding ascii" did not solve the problem when I tried it.

But now I must have had something weird, because today, I can't reproduce the results using the code sample I attached.  But I swear I had the issue, or I would have had no need to post at all.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is unrelated to encoding; the true problem is already explained in @AdminOfThings' comment, and it is easily reproduced: `$y = @(); $y = 'first'; $y += 'second'; $y` outputs `'firstsecond'`, i.e., a _single string_, because, despite _first_ creating `$y` as an _array_ (`$y = @()`), the next assignment, `$y = 'first'`, turns it into a _string_, and from then on `+=` performs _string concatenation_, not array building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) correctly points out:

- While **`$y = @()` assigns an empty array to `$y`**, it doesn't *type-constrain* that variable, so **your very next assignment - `$y = "Create Users process ..."` - *changes the variable type* to a *string***.

  - Simply using `+=` instead of `=` in that subsequent assignment would have prevented the problem: `$y += "Create Users process ..."`.
  - Alternatively, *type-constraining* the variable creation - `[array] $y = @()` - i.e., placing a type literal to the left of the variable being assigned (akin to a cast) - would have prevented the problem too.
- **Subsequent use of `+=` therefore performs simple *string concatenation*** rather than the desired gradual building of an array, with no separators between the "lines" added.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - By contrast, **had you used an *array* as intended, both `Out-File` and `Set-Content` would *automatically* insert platform-appropriate newlines<sup>[2]</sup> between the elements, plus one at the end, on saving** (in PSv5+ you can use the `-NoNewline` switch to opt out).

That said, using `+=` to "extend" an array is inefficient, because what PowerShell must do behind the scenes is create a *new* array containing the old elements plus the new one(s), given that arrays are *fixed-size* data structures.

While the performance penalty for use of `+=` to "extend" arrays in a loop only really matters with high iteration counts, it is more concise, convenient and efficient to **let PowerShell create arrays for you *implicitly*, by using your `foreach` loop as an *expression***:

```
# Initialize the array and assign the first element.
# Due to the type constraint ([array]), the RHS string implicitly becomes
# the array's 1st element.
[array] $y = "Create Users process.  Run started at $('[{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]' -f (Get-Date))"

# Add the strings output by the foreach loop to the array.
# PowerShell implicitly collects foreach output in an array when
# you use it in as an expression.
$y += foreach ($x in $users)
{
    "User $($x.displayname) with NNN of $($x.ID)"
}   

# Add the final string to the array.
$y += "Completed at $('[{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]' -f (Get-Date))"

# Send the array to a file with Out-File, which separates 
# the elements with newlines and adds a trailing one.
# Windows PowerShell:
#   Out-File creates UTF-16LE-encoded files.
#   Set-Content, which can alternatively be used, creates "ANSI"-encoded files.
# PowerShell Core:
#   Both cmdlets create UTF-8-encoded files without BOM.
$y | Out-File "Log.txt"
```

Note that **you can similarly use `for`, `if`, `do` / `while` / `switch` statements as expressions**.

In all cases, however, **as of PowerShell 7.0, these statements can only serve as expressions *by themselves***; regrettably, using them as the first segment of a pipeline or embedding them in larger expressions does *not* work - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817).

---

[1] A simple demonstration of your problem:

```
# The initialization of $y as @() is overridden by $y = 'first'.
PS> $y = @(); $y = 'first'; $y += 'second'; $y
firstsecond  # !! $y contains a single string built with string concatenation
```

The description of your symptoms is therefore not consistent with your code, as you should have seen a single-line output string in all scenarios (printing directly to the screen / via `Format-Table`, sending to a file and `type`-ing that from `cmd.exe`).

[2] The platform-appropriate newline is reflected in `[Environment]::NewLine`, and it is `` "`r`n" `` (CRLF) on Windows, and just `` "`n" `` (LF) on Unix-like platforms (in PowerShell *Core*).

Answer (score 1):

As using `+=` recreates the array on every iteration I'd suggest to assign the output of a `ForEach-Object` with it's `-Begin`, `-Process` and `-End` sections to a variable also using a more common approach of the format operator.:

```
$Log = $users | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    "Create Users process.  Run started at [{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
} -Process {
    "User {0} with NNN of {1}" -f $_.DisplayName,$_.ID
} -End {
    "Completed at [{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
}
$Log | Set-Content "Log.txt"
```

Comment: I have maybe 10 lines of data, so the overhead of the += is not impacting.  However, your answer omits why this works, and required a lot of code change versus just adding the needed CR/LF to the mix.

Comment: Because of the way his ForEach is written, each script block is going to output a string. Those strings are on their own lines which includes the line feed. The ForEach command itself outputs an array object with each element being a line output by the command. Sure, performance in this particular case may not matter, but it could in another example. The key point here though is that the formatting you want is **automatically** handled for you while giving you a more performant code block.

Comment: Good points, @AdminOfThings (I've removed the explicit newlines from the strings, because Jean-Claude's code didn't include them). However, note that, independently of the array-building performance, using the `ForEach-Object` _cmdlet_ in  a pipeline is much slower than a `foreach` _loop_. That said, this likely won't matter with small iteration counts, where the absolute execution duration is still small, and it certainly enables an elegant solution here.